# Postgres aggregate function returns wrong value, state transition function ok

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I've created an aggregate function in postgresql that is not returning the expected result, even when the transition function is working as expected. This are the definitions:

```sql
-- State: _hil overrides non hil

CREATE TYPE conversion_state AS (
  source text,
  source_hil text,
  ai text,
  ai_hil text,
  expert text
);
```

```sql
-- final state function:
-- if coalesced source is repair -> false
-- if expert is replace -> false
-- if coalesced ai is reapir -> true
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION conversion_final(conversion conversion_state)
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
  source text;
  ai_hil text;
BEGIN
    source = COALESCE(conversion.source_hil, conversion.source);
    IF source = 'REPAIR' THEN RETURN false; END IF;
    IF conversion.expert = 'REPLACE' THEN RETURN false; END IF;
    ai_hil := COALESCE(conversion.ai_hil, conversion.ai);
    RETURN ai_hil = 'REPAIR';
END;
$function$;
```

This function works as expected.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION conversion_state_transition(
  state conversion_state, stage enum_assessments_stage, assess text
) RETURNS organizer.rr_conversion_state
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
  r conversion_state;
BEGIN
    IF stage = 'source'
    THEN
        SELECT assess , state.source_hil, state.ai, state.ai_hil, state.expert INTO r.source, r.source_hil, r.ai, r.ai_hil, r.expert;
    END IF;
    IF stage = 'source_hil'
    THEN
        SELECT state.source, assess, state.ai, state.ai_hil, state.expert INTO r.source, r.source_hil, r.ai, r.ai_hil, r.expert;
    END IF;
    IF stage = 'ai'
    THEN
        SELECT state.source, state.source_hil, assess, state.ai_hil, state.expert INTO r.source, r.source_hil, r.ai, r.ai_hil, r.expert;
    END IF;
    IF stage = 'ai_hil'
    THEN
        SELECT state.source, state.source_hil, state.ai, assess, state.expert INTO r.source, r.source_hil, r.ai, r.ai_hil, r.expert;
    END IF;
    IF stage = 'expert'
    THEN
        SELECT state.source, state.source_hil, state.ai, state.ai_hil, assess INTO  r.source, r.source_hil, r.ai, r.ai_hil, r.expert;
    END IF;
    RETURN r;
END;
$function$;
```

The state transition function also works as expected, filling the respective state field with the assessment based on the stage value.

Now, the definition and use of the aggregate function is trivial:

```sql
-- Aggregate function. Use it to convert (stage, assessment_string) into conversion when assessments are group by (id, area)
CREATE AGGREGATE conversion_a(enum_assessments_stage, text)(
    SFUNC=conversion_state_transition,
    FINALFUNC=conversion_final,
    STYPE=conversion_state,
    INITCOND='(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)'
);


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW conversion AS
  SELECT assessments.id,
         assessments.area,
         conversion_a(assessments.stage, assessments.assessment_string) AS conversion
  FROM assessments
  WHERE assessments.type = 'REPAIR_REPLACE'
  GROUP BY assessments.id, assessments.area;
```

When I check the results of this view, I got the wrong results. Any idea of what could be happening? On one hand I suspect that grouping could be affecting the results, but I don't know how to fix it.